# cancel out integral on both sides

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

Is it safe to cancel out integral on both sides? For example

$$ \int_{x\in A}\frac{p_d(x)}{D(x)}dx = \int_{x\in A}\frac{p_g(x)}{1-D(x)}dx $$
$$ \frac{p_d(x)}{D(x)} = \frac{p_g(x)}{1-D(x)}$$

The integrals are over the same domain.

EDIT:
where
$$D(x) \in [0,1]$$
$$\int_\infty^\infty p_g(x) dx = 1 $$
$$\int_\infty^\infty p_d(x) dx = 1 $$

EDIT #2:
$$\int_{x\in A} p_g(x) dx = 1 $$
$$\int_{x\in A} p_d(x) dx = 1 $$

EDIT #3:

Trying to follow a proof on a GAN paper https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets.pdf . Beginning of page 5.

Basically the author comes to the conclusion that the "best response function" or the "reaction function" is:

Given the two player game:
$$\min_G \max_D V(D,G)=\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{data}(x)}\left[ \log D(x) \right ] + \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{z}(z)}\left[ \log \left(1 - D\left(G(z)\right)\right) \right ]$$
or equivalently

$$\min_G \max_D V(D,G)=\int_{x\in A} p_{data}(x) \log D(x)dx + \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{z}(z)}\left[ \log \left(1 - D\left(G(z)\right)\right) \right ]$$

to find the reaction function of maximizing player we can fix $G$ to $g$ and set $p_g(x)=p_z(g^{-1}(x))$ which leads to

$$ V(G,D) = \int_x p_{data}(x)\log D(x)  + p_g(x)\log(1-D(x))dx$$

Then applying the first-order condition for player $D$:

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial D}=\frac{\partial }{\partial D} \int_x p_{data}(x)\log D(x)  + p_g(x)\log(1-D(x))dx \equiv 0$$
$$\int_x \frac{\partial }{\partial D} \left [ p_{data}(x)\log D(x)  + p_g(x)\log(1-D(x)) \right] dx \equiv 0$$

$$ \int_{x\in A}\frac{p_d(x)}{D(x)}dx = \int_{x\in A}\frac{p_g(x)}{1-D(x)}dx $$

The authors claims that the reaction function is:

$$D^*_g(x) = \frac{p_{data}(x)}{p_{data}(x) + p_g(x)}$$

so wondering how they got that skipping a few steps.

Comment: You mean if this is true for any integral domain $A$ in the domain of $x$? Or even if known for some integral domain $A$?

Comment: @John Karasev In general it is absolutely illicit to ''cancel out" the integral, as you put it. Remember that since (definite) integrals are some sort of limits of particular types of sums, the notion of "cancelling out integrals" would have an informal analogue in that of "cancelling out finite summation". More explicitly, this would mean that given say two finite families $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^I$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i \in I}x_i=\displaystyle\sum_{i \in I}y_i$ one could claim that the families themselves are equal, $x=y$. This is clearly not the case in general.

Comment: @John Karasev *(cont.)* You would be able to infer the equality $x=y$ however under particular additional assumptions, such as for instance the one that the difference family $x-y$ has all members on the same (either positive or negative) semiaxis. This also applies to the integral situation: if two functions $f$ and $g$ have the same integral over a certain domain and if the difference $f-g$ is of a constant sign on that domain, then the difference will (essentially) vanish (almost everywhere) on that domain.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ, that is what I was thinking also. But I added some more conditions for the current context I am working with

Comment: @John Karasev The condition on $D$ ensures that the denominators of the integrands are positive, but without any supplementary hypothesis on the numerators I am afraid you can't draw too much of a conclusion.

Comment: @JohnKarasev In your EDIT section, shouldn't the lower bounds on the $2$ integrals be $-\infty$ instead of $\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Not in general at least.

For example,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \sin x dx = 2 = \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{2}{\pi} dx$

But clearly, $\sin x \neq \dfrac{2}{\pi} \quad \forall x \in [0, \pi]$

Comment: I added some more edits to give some other conditions to this problem

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, this is not a valid operation, though it could be in *very* specific circumstances. Even with your updated conditions, this is still not enough. For example, take $D(x)= \frac{1}{2}$. Then we have
$$
\int_{x \in A} 2p_d(x) \;dx = \int_{x \in A} 2p_g(x) \;dx
$$
Of course, we can then cancel the $2$'s to obtain
$$
\int_{x \in A} p_d(x) \;dx = \int_{x \in A} p_g(x) \;dx
$$
But of course, this is not enough to force $p_d(x)= p_g(x)$. You seem to want $p_d$ and $p_g$ to represent probability distributions. If $A= [0,1]$, choose $p_d(x)=1$ and $p_g(x)$ to be
$$
p_g(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x, & x \in [0,1/2) \\
2-2x & x \in [1/2,1]
\end{cases}
$$
Then the integrals are equal (both integral to $1$) but the functions are not the same. Worse even, I could have chosen any two distinct probability distributions on $[0,1]$, $p_d(x)$ and $p_g(x)$, and the integrals would both integrate to $1$ but certainly would not be equal. You can extent these functions on all of $\mathbb{R}$ simply by taking them to be $0$ outside of $[0,1]$.

Simply put, to get the condition you want, you're going to need very specific conditions on $p_d(x), p_g(x)$, and $D(x)$.

Comment: I added the paper that I am trying to follow the proof of. The EDIT #2 is all the conditions the authors use (at least what I caught). See EDIT#3.

Comment: They do set d(x) = 1/2 on page 5 proof of theorem 1, but they did not use this fact in the proposition they proved previously.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't cancel integrals. Goodfellow et al's 2014 GAN paper uses a calculus of variations argument (following the change of variables) in the proof of Proposition 1. This argument is *not* valid when dim(z) < dim(x) since the the generator output PDF $p_g(x)$ then contains delta functions. Please refer to section 2 of the paper:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/356815736_Convergence_and_Optimality_Analysis_of_Low-Dimensional_Generative_Adversarial_Networks_using_Error_Function_Integrals
for a simple explanation using a low-dimensional counter-example.